# user already login after logout in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

here i am using login session of state management for google signin phone sigin but after logout and restarting my again its goes to home screen i added all the details but not working the state code from firebase authentication with state

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _SplashScreenState();
  }
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
```

##here is my firebase code

```
  var auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var islogin = false;
  checkuserlogin() {
    auth.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if (user != null && mounted) {
        setState(() {
          islogin = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    startTimer();
    super.initState();
    checkuserlogin();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: const FlutterLogo(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void startTimer() {
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      navigateUser(); //It will redirect  after 3 seconds
    });
  }

  void navigateUser() async {
    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: ['email'],
    );
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Menu()));

      //Logged in via Number
    } else if (_googleSignIn.currentUser != null) {
      Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const UserScreen()));
      //Logged in via Gmail
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()));
      //Not Logged in
    }
  }
}
```